# Using Javascript to add "_blank" attribute to all links in a certain div

Tags: javascript, html, attr

I want all links in a certain div (which has a class) to open in a new window.

How can this be done using Javascript?

I'm just learning the basics of Javascript and I came across the following suggestion (from another post on this site), but it does not target all links under the specified class, which is where I'm stuck:

> document.getElementsByClassName('vertical-tabs-active-tab')[0].setAttribute("value", "yolo");

Comment: Yes, If you provide what you've tried so far.

Comment: I found an example, https://befused.com/jquery/open-link-new-window

Comment: Easily. Look into `querySelectorAll` and descendant selectors.

Comment: The `[0]` bit means you're only targeting the first element of the array.

Comment: @Clujio, thank you but my a elements don't have a class, it's the DIV that has the class

Comment: Add click event listener to your anchors, preventDefault, window.open(this.href, '_blank')

Comment: @DAE Did my solution work? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for div having class as bold :)

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("div.bold a");

links.forEach(link => {
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but its not working. What do i need to substitute other than "#divID a"? Let's say the DIV class is "bold" - should i put "div.bold a"?

Comment: Yes, indeed! :) @DAE

Comment: Thank you, though I'm seeing the following error in the console: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foreach' of null

Comment: It's forEach, not foreach. Mind the typo I had made. I have updated my code.

Comment: And yes, it must be querySelectorAll not querySelector actually as @Streiten suggested. I have updated my code. check again!

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on @UtkarshPramodGupta post. 
It's his proposed solution but you need querySelectorAll instead of querySelector:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("div.bold a");

links.forEach(link => {
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
})
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I have updated my code. Thanks for the heads up. :)